# ASP.NET MVC 1 to Azure migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, azure

I have a web application built with ASP.NET MVC 1 in Visual Studio 2008.

How do I migrate this web application to Azure? All the tutorials are either for Visual Studio 2010 or don't work anymore. I've installed the Web Platform Installer and the Azure SDK, and in VS2010 the Azure project template is available, but not in VS2008. I've checked alot of guides, but all the download links on MSDN for anything Visual Studio 2008 related seem to be broken.

My idea was just to add an Azure deployment project to the solution, add the references to the right Azure libraries, and deploy, but I can't even get that far since I have no idea where to begin.

Much of the MVC stuff in my application is highly customized, making a migration to ASP.NET MVC 2/3/4 difficult. And since it's MVC 1, which has no tooling support for Visual Studio 2010, I would preferably avoid a migration to Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading? You only need to get to MVC 2 I think. What issues are blocking you?

Answer (score 1):

You can go about this in two ways.  You can either use cspack to package up the code and deploy to Azure or you can install an older SDK that supports Visual Studio 2008:

CSPack: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432988.aspx

Older SDKs: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/downloads/archive-net-downloads/

I know 1.1 installed on VS2008 and I know 1.4 does not, not sure about the ones in between.

Comment: What about Dev Fabric? I can't seem to find that anywhere after installing the v1.1 Azure SDK and the v1.1 Azure Tools for VS.